# linux go program how to acknowledge it has run

Tags: go, desktop, linux-mint

Apologies in advance but I am a recent "convert" from Windows to Linux. Have a Go binary which looks at my NAS and emails me a report on the content. It is invoked by double clicking a desktop icon. However there is no acknowledgement that it has run, only receipt of the emails some 30 seconds later. Is there a simple way in Linux desktop to show it has actually run? Again, apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: A traditional Go binary is not really a "desktop application", it's a command-line application. Try running it in a terminal, or creating an application definition for your OS that will run your binary in a persistent terminal.

Comment: OK I understand that - in Windows I would have run it in Dos or Powershell "box" and then I would have known when it ended I would hit return and the box would close - none of this would have required any extra code. So I need to set up a "desktop" item that points to a Terminal a runs the binary in that. Better start to readmy linux 101. Thanks.